# Get data in my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, android-viewholder

I started to work with Retrofit. In my application i have one RecyclerView with two ViewHolder's, where trying to get data from my models, in logs coming *type*:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
        DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
        Log.d("type",jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss().get(1).getmControls().get(2).getTitle()+"");
        adapter = new DataAdapter(response.body());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

How can I display this *type* in my RecyclerView, if there will be a few types?
Now i get next message:

> 09-13 09:20:40.958 2798-2798/com.random.secondproject E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

DataAdapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

public static final String TYPE_TEXTVIEW = "0";
public static final String TYPE_EDITVIEW = "1";
private DropDown mList;

public DataAdapter(DropDown list) {
    this.mList = list;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case 0:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_numeric, parent, false);
            return new NumericViewHolder(view);
        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drop_down_options, parent, false);
            return new DropDownViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DropDown object = mList.get(position);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.getTitle()){
            case TYPE_TEXTVIEW:
                ((NumericViewHolder) holder).title.setText(String.valueOf(object.getTitle()));
                break;
            case TYPE_EDITVIEW:
                ((DropDownViewHolder) holder).title_options.setText(String.valueOf(object.getTitle()));
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mList == null)
        return 0;
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    DropDown object = mList.get(position);
        if (object.getTitle().equals("drop_down_options"))
        return 0;
    else return 1;
}

public class NumericViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private  TextView title;

    public NumericViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}

public class DropDownViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private EditText title_options;

    public DropDownViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title_options = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_options);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm going to take two types (TextView and EditText)
so I will write a few ways to model(array i think). For example, as I wrote in Log.d .

Comment: I assume you get that message before **onResponse** is called, right?

Comment: Yes, i can show all my code in MainActivity if it's necessary.
Want to understand the issue.

Comment: Assuming the log.d is printing value type and title. Please can you add DataAdapter code by editing question

Answer (score 0):

Everything seem ok to me in your adapter. Try to call **recyclerView.invalidate()**. The idea is that you draw your RecyclerView before calling the **onResponse** method. Thus, you have empty view. The **invalidate()** method will try to redraw the view.

Comment: Same problem.
The problem is that I'm not sure that the correct output the data in RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

There are some error so that `onResponse` function not call, or you do with element in recyclerview before onResponse called.

You need create an adapter with empty Dropdown

```
adapter = new DataAdapter(new Dropdown());
```

When onResponse called you only `notifyDatasetChange` to adapter, don't `setAdapter` again.

Or you put the code that pratice with element of recyclerview to onResponse.

Comment: But, how can I change the call in the list instead of logs?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't know about your Dropdown class.   You can create an global variable: mDropdown = new Dropdown(), then after onResponse called you clear mDropdown by mDropdown.clear then add new value: mDropdown.add(response.body()).